# Part of a sorted array is reversed

Tags: c++, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given a sorted array, a part of which is reversed. We are required to completely sort it.
eg :

```
ip - 2 4 5 7 13 11 9 14 19
op - 2 4 5 7 9 11 13 14 19
```

It's easy to solve when we know whether the given array is sorted in ascending or descending order.If we don't know the order, how to solve it?

eg:

```
ip - 19 17 2 6 8 10 1
op - 19 17 10 8 6 2 1
```

also ambiguity occurs when 1st part of input is in ascending order and remaining is in descending order.In that case any order can be considered for output.

Answer (score 0):

1. Assume the final result should be ascending. Run your algorithm once.
2. Check whether the output is really ascending. If yes, we are done; if no, go to 3.
3. Roll back to original input, assume the final result should be descending, run your algorithm once.
4. Check whether the output is really descending. If yes, we are done; if no, the input is illegal.